# How to send file with Email in Laravel Nova?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8, laravel-nova

I am sending a `Newsletter Email` to multiple recipients in `markdown` but I can't seem to attach a file to the email. The sending is triggered through an `action`:

**`Resource`**:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),

        Date::make('Created', 'created_at'),

        Markdown::make('Message', 'content')->alwaysShow(),

        File::make('File')->disk('public')
    ];
}

public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        Actions\NewsletterMail::make()->standalone()
    ];
}
```

**`Action`** triggers controller function `send`:

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
{
    app(NewsletterMailController::class)->send();
}
```

**`Controller`** gets all recipients emails and sends `mailable` to them:

```
public function send()
{
    $emails = DB::select('select * from newsletter_recipients order by id desc');

    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        Mail::to($email)->send(new NewsletterMail());
    }
}
```

**`Mailable`** gets the current `newsletter email` and returns it as `markdown`:

```
public function build()
{
    $this->content = DB::select('select * from newsletter_mails order by id desc limit 1')[0]->content;

    return $this->markdown('emails.newsletter')->with('content', $this->content);
}
```

As you can see the `resource` has an `file field`. I can assign a file to it in the `nova dashboard` but when the emails are sent, it arrives without attachment.

Anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use attach function in order to send files as attachments to email.

You can try this instead

```
return $this->markdown('emails.newsletter')
->with('content', $this->content)
->attach(filePath, ['as' => fileName,'mime' => 'application/pdf']);
```

Filepath will be location where your file is stored, make sure that folder has read write access.

Above code will send file as an attachment in your emails.